# set spinner mode in XML

Tags: android, xml, spinner

When defining a spinner in code, you can set the mode to 'dialog' or 'dropdown':

> Spinner(Context context, int mode)
>   Construct a new spinner with the given context's theme and the supplied mode of displaying choices.

But I can't find this option when defining my layout in XML. Did I just miss it, or is this not possible in XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, according to the reference found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) this is not possible. There is no corresponding XML attribute listed. Like other things as setting 24h mode for a timepicker, which is not possible in XML.

Answer (score 18):

As of API level 11, you can use

```
<Spinner style="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown" ... />
```

or

```
<Spinner android:spinnerMode="dropdown" ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the API level 10 or lower just remove android:spinnerMode and style from your XML file.

Answer (score 1):

**To** use `SpinnerMode` Xml attribute and work on API Level 11 or higher.

you need to  create your own style for spinner.

1] put in `themes.xml` file in `values` Folder :

```
<style name="spinner_style" >
    <item name="spinnerMode">dialog</item>
</style>
```

2] put in `themes.xml` file in `values-v11` Folder and `values-v14` Folder :

```
<style name="spinner_style" >
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dialog</item>
</style>
```

3] then use your style in `Spinner` xml tag

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        style="@style/spinner_style"/>
```

Comment: According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#spinnerMode), the `spinnerMode` attribute was added in API level 11, not level 10.